# Presenting from window.rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8

In my app, I set the window's rootViewController in `willFinishLaunching`. Standard.

In `didFinishLaunching`, I check to see if the user is logged in, and if not, I present a LoginViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunching...
{
    ...

    self.window.rootViewController = [MyViewController new];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    ...

    return true;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunching...
{
    if (/* not logged in */) {
        UIViewController *login = [LoginViewController new];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcome];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:false completion:nil];
    }

    return true;
}
```

In iOS 7, this works perfectly. However, in iOS 8, I see the following warnings in my console:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LoginViewController: 0x7fca9340cbb0>.
```

I'm not quite sure what I need to do to avoid this warning while still being able to present my LoginViewController.

I like presenting from `window.rootViewController` because it allows me to dismiss `LoginViewController` when the user logs in without having to add completion/callback code to any other view controllers in my application.

Any ideas?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088465/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-detailviewcontroller

Comment: thanks. weird though that i don't receive that warning in iOS 7.

Comment: It's not something that was.. a thing.. in iOS7, that's why you didn't see it. :)

Comment: try using [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; just before presenting your navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to present view controller with some delay. I have used this trick in one of my project.

```
-(void)presentController
{
        UIViewController *login = [LoginViewController new];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcome];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:false completion:nil];
}
```

call this method with performSelector with delay

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(presentController) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
```