# How to pop to head of navigation view from a non-navigation view

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to go back to the head of the navigation from a non-navigation view.

I tried passing the parent view controller from Nav2 to PayPalVC to MyViewController and using this following statement in MyViewController:

Note: The syntax is in C#

```
parent.NavigationController.PopToViewController(parent.NavigationController.ViewControllers[0], true);
```

This how it is set up:

RootViewController -> Head of Navigation -> Navigation 1 -> Navigation 2 -> PayPalViewController -> MyViewController -> Back to Head of Navigation

Comment: `UINavigationController` has a specific method to pop back to its root view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController.PopToRootViewController
```

as..

```
parent.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

*not sure what parent is but may be redundant here*

> **Parameters**
>
> *animated*: A boolean indicating if the transition back to the root controller should be animated.
>
> **Returns** An array of view controller that were popped from the stack in the process of returning to the root controller.
>
> **Remarks**   After this call, the root controller will be at the top of the UINavigationController's stack, and the root controller's view
>   will be displayed by the navigation controller.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController.PopToRootViewController/p/System.Boolean/

Comment: parent is the view controller of Navigation 2's view controller. I passed that view controller to PayPalVC ann onto MyVC. I tried your suggestion and I got message on the console that reads: "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transition for <nav head view controller>"

Comment: Here is a post describing the issue, not sure if it helps. Could just try changing the `true` to `false` for the animation paramter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088465/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-detailviewcontroller