# How to correctly close modal presented controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am opening a navigationController using either directly navigation segue in storyboard or called segue from code, but still created on storyboard.

Example:

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addNew", sender: nil)
```

Which then with modal transition opens a navigationController. NC then has a few view controllers on which all have close button on them and when I click on it it closes NC using:

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But afterwards when I switch between different ViewControllers on TabbarController or open some other view with push view I get:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
```

And also viewWillAppear on opened view isn't called. So can anyone tell me if I'm closing the NC correctly or is there some other way to prevent the error.

EDIT1:
changed the closing call from
    controller.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

to self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) just to make the question easier.

Also tired:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
```

EDIT2:
Is it maybe bad to open a NC from VC that is on NC that is on UITabbarController or is just simply already bad to have NavigationControllers as tabs on TabbarController?

Comment: `self.navigationContro......`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for DetailViewController" when pushing more than one detail view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088465/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-detailviewcontroller)

Comment: @Oleg Gordiichuk don't think so, since if I never call other NC there problem dosen't appear

Answer (score 3):

You may need to close the controller from that controller's side:

```
// place this to the target controller, which handles you that modal view
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    //completion:
}
```

or

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: With this line I get the problem even faster, but thanks for suggestion

Comment: Well, where have you placed that line? In what method?

Comment: I replaced the self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: But where, in what method? :) I am asking the method, where you have placed whichever from suggested lines.

Comment: In a method that is called from button in navigation bar. Method is written on the controller that is currently on top in NC