# (2022) Getting error: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x7fd050035000>

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

All previous answers to this question appear to be very outdated and in Objective-C. I created a new project and in scene delegate 'scene' func, added the following code for my root viewController:

```
  guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
    window.rootViewController = nav
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I then created that controller and made the background color red to test UI. It didn't work. Print statements running the the viewDidLoad run, but the UI does not run. I always do this and never get this error... any help is appreciated.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088465/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-detailviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a line...

```
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
    window.rootViewController = nav
    
    // missing this line
    self.window = window
    
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```