# UIWindow in SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, uikit, uiwindow, uiscenedelegate, uiscene

Recently, I encountered a problem, which I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038000/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-viewcontroller-0), in stackoverflow. Apparently, the error was because a random UIWindow variable was used to display UI (and not the one in SceneDelegate).

Here's my understanding - Every time a scene is created (by user or the app), a [UISceneSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenesession) is created to manage a [UIScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene), which can contain one or more [UIWindows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow), each of which has views, which are displayed with the help of a view controller. Each UIScene will get a [UISceneDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate) object to handle its lifecycle.

The error in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038000/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-viewcontroller-0) makes sense now - since a random UIWindow object was used instead of the one in SceneDelegate.

But I still don't completely understand why a UIWindow was declared in the SceneDelegate by Xcode. There's a UIWindow object in [UIWindowSceneDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate) (super class of my current SceneDelegate) and the documentation clearly explains that its a window associated with the scene.
Why isn't that used and instead a new variable is created by Xcode while creating the project? If I need another window, then can I just add another UIWindow object to the current SceneDelegate? Is that a good practice?

```
@available (iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    // Remaining methods
}
```

I'm new to swift and iOS app development - any help to fill in these blanks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIWindowSceneDelegate is not the superclass of your scene delegate. It is a *protocol*. It isn't an actual thing. It is merely a set of *instructions* telling the compiler what it would mean to *adopt* this protocol. Your SceneDelegate class *does* adopt the UIWindowSceneDelegate protocol. Therefore it *must* declare a `window` property of type `UIWindow?` — and it does so.

Moreover, this property *is* the scene delegate's window; without it, you would have no window and the screen would be black. You *could* in fact *set* this property to a window that you make yourself; but you don't have to, and so you probably don't bother. You don't have to because the framework does it automatically for you as part of the scene-creation process.

Comment: Oh, it all makes sense now. Thanks a lot :).